# Problem with testsaslauthd and kerberos5 ("saslauthd internal error")

Tags: linux, security, kerberos, sasl

The error message “saslauthd internal error” seems like a catch-all for saslauthd, so I’m not sure if it’s a red herring, but here’s the brief description of my problem:

This Kerberos command works fine:

```
$ echo getprivs | kadmin -p username -w password
Authenticating as principal username with password.
kadmin:  getprivs
current privileges: GET ADD MODIFY DELETE
```

But this SASL test command fails:

```
$ testsaslauthd -u username -p password
0: NO "authentication failed"
```

saslauthd works fine with "-a sasldb", but the above is with "-a kerberos5"

This is the most detail I seem to be able to get from saslauthd:

```
saslauthd[]: auth_krb5: krb5_get_init_creds_password: -1765328353
saslauthd[]: do_auth : auth failure: [user=username] [service=imap]
                 [realm=] [mech=kerberos5] [reason=saslauthd internal error]
```

Kerberos seems happy:

```
krb5kdc[](info): AS_REQ (4 etypes {18 17 16 23}) 127.0.0.1:
                 ISSUE: authtime 1298779891, etypes {rep=18 tkt=18 ses=18},
                 username at REALM for krbtgt/DOMAIN at REALM
```

I’m running Ubuntu 10.04 (lucid) with the latest updates, namely:

- Kerberos 5 release 1.8.1
- saslauthd 2.1.23

Thanks for any clues.

Answer (score 1):

```
auth_krb5: krb5_get_init_creds_password: -1765328353
```

This is the only useful bit. You do have the error code, the tricky part is turning that error into a useful message. Some google fu yields

[https://andromeda.rutgers.edu/~sysmail/krb5_error.html](https://andromeda.rutgers.edu/%7Esysmail/krb5_error.html) (which has since gone offline, but is available on the [Internet Archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20140901094501/https://andromeda.rutgers.edu/%7Esysmail/krb5_error.html))

Decrypt Integrity check failed.

Anybody can get a tgt from the kdc, but not everybody can decrypt it to make it useful. It really looks like you don't have the right password.

http://www.cmf.nrl.navy.mil/krb/kerberos-faq.html#badpass (→ [Internet Archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20161216193939/https://www.cmf.nrl.navy.mil/krb/kerberos-faq.html#badpass))

Do you have a keytab for saslauthd to validate logins?

Comment: It can also be helpful to put them in hex (this one is 96C73A1F; they are 32-bit signed numbers), and check that.  Sometimes (not this time) the lower 16 bits of that are in the MSDN and are a standard error.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

- specifying username@REALM
- obtaining TGT with `kinit`: Kerberos should work without supplying passwords anywhere else.